# Trouble with basic Python recursion

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble figuring out why my code is not working, and would appreciate if someone could point out what I'm missing.  It's a basic algorithm problem: given a set of distinct sorted integers, determine whether there is an element such that a[i] = i (a[3] = 3, for example).

I've tried to debug it using print statements, but it's only making one call to FindIndex and not recursing.

Here's the code:

```
import math

def FindIndex(SetToSearch, beginningIndex, endingIndex):
    """Searches a list of sorted integers to see if there is some a[i] == i

    Keyword Arguments:
    SetToSearch -- a list of disctinct sorted integers 
    beginningIndex -- start point of index to search
    endingIndex -- end point to search """
    # calculate midpoint of set
    midpointIndex = math.ceil((beginningIndex + endingIndex) / 2)
    midpoint = SetToSearch[int(midpointIndex)]
    print "beginningIndex: %s, endingIndex: %s" %(beginningIndex,endingIndex)
    print "midpointIndex: %s, midpoint: %s" % (midpointIndex, midpoint)
    # check whether ending index is greater then beginning index
    if (endingIndex > beginningIndex):
        return "There is no value in this set such that a[i] = i"
    if (endingIndex == beginningIndex):
        if SetToSearch[beginningIndex] == SetToSearch[endingIndex]:
            return "a[%s] is equal to %s" % [beginningIndex, beginningIndex]
    if (midpoint == midpointIndex):
        return "The value at index %d" % midpointIndex
    if (midpoint > midpointIndex):
        print "midpoint > midpointIndex evaluated to true and executed this"
        return FindIndex(SetToSearch, 0, midpointIndex)
    if (midpoint < midpointIndex):
        print "midpoint < midpointIndex evaluated to true and executed this"
        return FindIndex(SetToSearch, midpointIndex + 1, len(SetToSearch) -1)
    else:
        "Something is wrong with your program, because you should never see this!"

sampleSet = [-10, -8, -6, -5, -3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9 ]
lastIndex = len(sampleSet) - 1

FindIndex(sampleSet,0,lastIndex)
```

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?

Comment: Your syntax at the end of the else is invalid.  It won't do what you think it will.

Comment: The first call to `FindIndex` returned expected results for the first `print` statements: `beginningIndex: 0, endingIndex: 9
midpointIndex: 4.0, midpoint: -3`.  None of the conditionals, including the `else` executed.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think your `math.ceil` line quite works. You're using Python 2, so `(beginningIndex + endingIndex) / 2` always returns an integer.  If you want to round up when `beginningIndex + endingIndex` is odd, you could divide by `2.0` instead, to make sure it's a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't recursion. It's just that your first condition is always true: `endingIndex` is always greater than `beginningIndex`. That condition returns without recursion, so the function ends there.

Comment: Thanks...careless mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `for` loop like :

```
def find_index_equal_value(set):
    for i in range(0, len(set)):
        val = set[i]
        if(val == i):
           print "Index matches value."
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must add `return` to the start of line 48.
Second, add `print` to start of last line.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you can't see what happened, it's because you need to print the returned string:

```
print FindIndex(sampleSet,0,lastIndex)
```

Now, if I run it I get:

```
beginningIndex: 0, endingIndex: 9
midpointIndex: 4.0, midpoint: -3
There is no value in this set such that a[i] = i
```

which means this `if` matched:

```
# check whether ending index is greater then beginning index
if (endingIndex > beginningIndex):
    return "There is no value in this set such that a[i] = i"
```

... well, of course it did - `endingIndex` *should* always be greater than `beginningIndex`!

---

For future reference, did you print the string? Did you see the output line and not understand why it took that branch? Did you try stepping through the code with `pdb`?

Comment: No to both, but thanks for the two tips.  I'll be sure to use those going forward.